# Issue with positioning in CSS

Tags: html, css, position

I'm trying to master this positioning stuff. I have an understanding (sort of) of ABSOLUTE, RELATIVE and STATIC.

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a few images and items I want to overlay in simple div sections.

```
---------------------------------------------------
|                                                 |
|                    Div 1                        |
|                                                 |
---------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
|                                                 |
|                    Div 2                        |
|                                                 |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Now, Div 1 and Div 2 will have 'background' images (lower z-index), but I want to overlay images over them as well.

```
<div class="menubar">
    <img class="bar" src=...>
    <img class="logo" src=...>
    <table class="mytab">...</table>
</div>
<div class="div2">
    <img class="bgimg" src=...>
    <img class="overlay img1" src=...>
    <img class="overlay img2" src=...>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.menubar {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: static;
    height:100px;
}
.bar {
    width:1000px;
    height:75px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 3;
}
.logo {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    top:+15px;
    left:+400px;
}
.mytab{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    left:+10px;
    top:+2px;
}

.div2{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: static;
    height:100px;
}
.bgimg{
    width:1000px;
    position:absolute;
    height:131px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
.overlay.img1 {
    width:323px;
    top: +18px;
    left: +677px;
}
.overlay.img2 {
    width:323px;
    top: +18px;
    left: +277px;
}
```

What's happening:

The first DIV is displaying correctly with all elements showing up where they are supposed to.

For DIV2, the bgimg shows up where it is supposed to (at 0,0 of Div2). However, the other images in Div2 (img1, img2) are absolute at coordinates from 0,0 of DIV1, not DIV2!

Why?

One additional question as a followup: say img1 in div 2 stretches outside the width of div2. I have the css as above to overflow:hidden for div2, yet the image still shows in full. Any idea why it isn't cut off? (Ignore the sizes in my sample code it was simplified for this question, just assume it stretches out)

Comment: In plain CSS, you can't do things like `top:+2px;`.

Comment: hmm... that part seems to be working for me. Thought I can change it. Update: I removed all +'s, everything still the same

Comment: At a quick guess, I imagine they won't actually be position 0,0 of DIV1, but rather 0,0 of the page (which happens to also be 0,0 of DIV1). DIV1 & DIV2 will probably have to be `position:relative`

Comment: Your div2 needs position diferent from static... like realtive in order to be the point of reference for the absolute childrens

Comment: One additional question as a followup: say img2 in div 2 stretches outside the width of div2. I have the css as above to overflow:hidden for div2, yet the image still shows in full. Any idea why it isn't cut off? (Ignore the sizes in my code, just assume it stretches out)

Comment: @NEW2WEB Tested a basic version quickly http://jsfiddle.net/ux7fgnqr/ and the overflow is cut off correctly. There must be something else at work in your code, would it be possible to replicate what you have in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @MLeFevre - you were right. I was not putting a width on Div2. Thanks again!

Comment: @MLeFevre - can you put your responses in an answer so I can mark it accepted?

Comment: @NEW2WEB sure, I've posted a few examples in an answer showing the behavior more clearly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements that have `position:absolute` need to have parent's that have `position:relative;`, to tell them be be positioned relative to them. If they're not, their children would [position themselves relative to the page itself](http://jsfiddle.net/ux7fgnqr/1/).

```
div {
    height:150px;
}

img {
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

If you give your 2 container divs `position:relative;`, then the absolutely positioned elements within them will be [adjusted relative to their parents position](http://jsfiddle.net/ux7fgnqr/2/).

```
div {
    position:relative;
    height:150px;
}

img {
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

and as requested, you can then apply `overflow:hidden` to essentially [crop any overflow of the images](http://jsfiddle.net/ux7fgnqr/3/).